# How fix cannot find module 'svg-baker-runtime/symbol' in svg-sprite-loader?

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack

I use svg-sprite-loader for one folder in project, so i have such config:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|svg|ico)$/,
      exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/Icon',
      use: 'file?name=/img/[folder]_[name].[ext]'
    },

    {
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: 'svg-sprite-loader',
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/Icon')
    }
  ]
}
```

and I saw this error:

```
Cannot find module 'svg-baker-runtime/symbol'
```

Comment: typo ? path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/Icon'